# How do I reference another class into another class in C++?

Tags: c++

I've been trying to reference another class inside of a class in C++ and I have no idea how.
I have created a small program to demonstrate the issue

```
#include <iostream>
class foo{
    public:
    int variable1 = 012;
};

class bar{
    public:
    int getFooVariable(){
        return variable1; // How would I get bar to refrence foo in foobar?
    }
};

class foobar{
    public:
    bar p1;
    foo p2;
};

int main(){
    foobar fb;
    std::cout << fb.p1.getFooVariable(); << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

How would I solve this problem?

Comment: The small program demonstrates a few things: you've forgotten `#include <iostream>`, and you've forgotten a few `;`s. Not a clean job, I'd say, so I'm not reading further.

Comment: There is a distinction between classes and instances. You want to access the parent instance. so pass 'this' pointer to foobar so you can access the parent.

Comment: @Enlico Sorry about that

Comment: @RichardCritten I see then, how would i pass bar into my function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for **dependency injection**:

```
class foo
{
public:
    int variable1 = 012;
};

class bar
{
    foo _foo;
public:
    bar(foo& fooInjected) :
        _foo(fooInjected)
    {}
    int getFooVariable() { return _foo.variable1; }
};
```

There is an idea of **inversion of control**: bar has no control over the creation of foo instance, which is created outside. It's a common way to inject for instance a service. It's also a very important way to loosely couple classes working together and to mock and to test them. But here foo is a concrete class, instead and ideally you're refering only an interface (c#) or an abstract class (c++) in bar. Which concrete class is behind is out of control of bar. I recommend M. Seeman's book *Dependency Injection in .NET* to understand this completely.

or **inheritance**:

```
class foo
{
public:
    int variable1 = 012;
};

class bar: public foo
{
public:
    int getFooVariable() { return variable1; }
};
```

Here, bar builds up heavily on foo. bar is a "richer version" of foo if this makes sense. This is what to choose if there is a high cohesion inside bar.

Invoking a variable through another's instance function is a most horrid idea, that goes against [class cohesion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_(computer_science)):

```
int getFooVariable(foo* foo) { return foo->variable1; }
```

Comment: Remote accessing of variables of an object through a reference is quite fine. Cohesion is a much larger concept that has to do with the way groups of classes communicate with other groups of classes, not the individual class to class. Individual classes can be strongly coupled and is good. See https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/09/CouplingVsCohesion.svg/1920px-CouplingVsCohesion.svg.png here, notice the dots in the box are all coupled to each other, but between boxes there are few connections. Each box represents a logical group of classes and each dot a class.

Comment: @RichardBamford Strong coupling is just bad, one want loose coupling. Your claims go against all good practices. Including S of SOLID. You want to read https://blog.ndepend.com/lack-of-cohesion-methods/, Dependency Injection in .NET (Seeman) and learn more about maintainability.

Comment: I think you are getting mixed up, the whole cohesion concept is based on the information hiding principle. This seminal paper by David Parnas defined it: https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/361598.361623

Comment: @RichardBamford Cohesion is about relation (x uses y) between members. You may hide or not, this happens independently. It's the other way around. It's exactly what I commented about DI (decoupled ∧ hiding) vs inheritance (cohesion ∧ no hiding).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to change the formatting, here's a solution:

```
#include iostream
class foo
{
public:
    int variable1 = 012;
};

class bar
{
public:
    int getFooVariable(foo* foo)
    {
        return foo->variable1; // How would I get bar to refrence foo in foobar?
    }
};

class foobar
{
public:
    bar p1;
    foo p2;
};

int main()
{
    foobar fb;
    std::cout << fb.p1.getFooVariable(&(fb.p2));
    << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

You can add a parameter to the getFooVariable() function to take a foo* reference. The reference can be found when you call the function.